# .jsp page not working with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have built a path from Eclipse to the home directory of the jdk. 
As you can see here: [image: http://s18.postimage.org/9sj7vfx21/picture.png]

Below is my index page that is first loaded when I start my server on localhost.

The jsp file is not displaying properly as it lets the user see the actual code.
Is there something else I need to do?

```
// index.jsp //
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" %> 
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome! </h1>
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/viewfiles" />View Files</a>
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/upload.jsp" />Upload Files</a>
    <p>
       Today's date: <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString()%>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check:

1. JDK 1.7 is experimental in GAE, so you need to make sure that things are configured for it:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/java7    You might want to consider sticking with 1.6 for now, anyway.
2. You probably need to check your web.xml, as that is the place where the application is really configured.  See:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml
3. This is probably something that you are going to fix, but of course localhost URLs aren't going to work as one might expect when you actually deploy the app.

Comment: What happens when you try http://localhost:8080/index.jsp ? (assuming you're using port 8080)

Comment: If I have XAMPP running with Tomcat enabled it works. Otherwise it doesn't work.